# C# Remote application execution

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create some sort of remote application execution programs. The situation is that I have a script on a remote pc that I need to execute. Ideally I could do with being able to tell this remote pc to execute this script as though I was at it locally.

If possible it would be executable without the need to login to the pc (such as sending login details etc). I'm going for using .net c#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The best code is code that you don't have to write yourself.* Take a look at [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) from Microsoft (SysInternals). Assuming that you have common credentials with the remote machine (either by virtue of a domain login or the same password and username), it should "Just Work".

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows you to do just that.  If you need .NET bindings for it, they are in the [`System.Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace

Answer (score 0):

I WOULD GO with what Rob or Daniel suggested, but if you want to do something dirty (don't) you could write a small service that you'd register on the remote PCs that would just watch for a specific trigger. For example, the service could periodically check a network drive for a file, a database for some parameters, etc.

But as I said previously, this is something I would do if I'd want something really temporary and wouldn't want to spend time to learn how to do it properly.

Comment: ... or if I needed to do it a lot on a finite set of computers I control.